# SSL certificate error : certificate file does not exist or is empty

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, magento

I am getting this error on `service apache2 restart`

```
Error: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/apache2/ssl/www_example_com.crt' does not exist or is empty
```

I am trying to configure comodo ssl certificate on ubuntu ec2 instance with LAMP and I have performed all official steps by following below links.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/httpd.html#https-configuration

Please help.

Comment: Did you check if the certificates are in there?

Comment: where is your comodo cert?

Comment: all three certificates are there /etc/ssl
www_example_com.crt
www_example_com.ca-bundle
www_example_com.key

Comment: Is the virtualhost file properly configured to point to the certificate location?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1259607/1144775 I had the same problem, this answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following:

1. The certificate is actually present at the location.
2. The certificate is not empty.

Having done that, you can then try to check your sites's `virtual host` file.

In the `/etc/apache2` folder there is `sites-enabled` folder which has the `virtual hosts` file as symlinks with `sites-available` folder.

Not you can check the virtual host file either in  `sites-available` or `sites-enabled` folder.

The correct form should be :

```
<VirtualHost IP ADDRESS :443 >
DocumentRoot <path/to/sites/folder>
ServerName <domain name>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/primary.crt                 #edit path as needed
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/private.key              #edit path as needed
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt       #edit path as needed
#Include /etc/options-ssl-apache.conf #optional for some configs

</VirtualHost>
```

Of course : **Change the names of the files and paths to match your certificate files**:

```
SSLCertificateFile should be your primary certificate file for your domain name.
SSLCertificateKeyFile should be the key file generated when you created the Certificate signing reques.
SSLCertificateChainFile should be the intermediate certificate file (if any) that was supplied by your certificate authority.
```

Save the changes and exit the text editor after making appropriate changes.
Restart your Apache web server using one of the following commands:

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl startssl
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because of following

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.example.com.pem;
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.pdchealthcare.com.pem;
```

after replacing with

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.example.com.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.example.com.pem
```

the error was gone(Notice the ; removed) and I was able to restart the Apache server.